# Logging data from on-premises SQL Server to Azure App Insights

Tags: sql-server, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

**Question**: Data stored/generated in on-premises SQL server needs to be logged to app insights. This data represents both the *temporary* data that is passed to stored procedures and also *concrete* data that is stored in tables. I am asking this question to figure out if there is any direct way to do this. I have come up with the following options till now, in case there is no direct solution please let me know which is the most suited option for the task.

**Options**:

1. Log that data into a temporary table and have a windows service/ azure web job that picks up that data in batches and does the logging.
2. Use a SQL CLR stored procedure that logs the data directly to app insights using Azure App Insights DLL
3. Use Azure Data Factory to export the data from on-premise SQL server to some Azure based storage and then to App Insights

Comment: You really want to do this? Realize this will be a costly operation depending on the quantity and size of your data. What kind of data are we talking about? AI is meant to help you troubleshooting your app and gain insights in the usings and workings. It is not for business data analysis.

Comment: If you want to log data requests to AI it makes more sense, depending on your data access strategy there might be some options. We have used interception in Entity Framework for example to do just that.

Comment: @partycoder: Application server is not a choice since its a pre .NET application.

Comment: @PeterBons : The amount of data logged won't be significant. As I mentioned in my previous comment, its a legacy application and tracking data passed into SQL server is our only option of understanding user behavior and troubleshooting possible problems. The data access happens directly through SQL queries and there is no ORM in place.

Comment: Then probably option 2 would be your best bet. Maybe use triggers for the concrete data (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131093(SQL.100).aspx)

Comment: @PeterBons: Thanks, will give it a shot. Though folks here aren't too fond of using AppInsights DLL for making Azure service calls in SQL Server process.

Comment: With Application Analytics you can also analyze your own data which is not  limited to AI schema, by adding a new data source and import your data to it. More details can be found in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-import
Note that you can also use LogStash with AIAnalytics output to send the data from your on-prem server